# Correct romanization for ベオウルフ (Beowulf) and the use of ō

Tags: katakana, rōmaji, long-vowels

I want to know the correct romanization for ベオウルフ.

For me, it's Beōrufu, because the pronunciation of Be-o-wulf has a long vowel (oo/ou/ow/oh). However, some people discord for being a foreign name.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, using the macron for indicating long vowels is only really used in (Revised) Hepburn romanization, so "correct" would mean "according to the rules of Hepburn romanization".

Secondly, Hepburn only uses ō for *long* vowels and here there isn't one! One way that points to this fact is that the word in katakana isn't spelled オー, but オウ.

Actually, ベオウルフ is a good transcription because for one it reflects the fact that the ウ is a substitution for "wu" (definitely not a lengthener of "o"); further, it suggest the pitch as ベオウルフ【LHHLL】, whereas ベオールフ would have to be ベオールフ【LHLLL】 (the former is much closer to the English pronunciation, which has a secondary stress at "wu").

In any case, I think you should romanize ベオウルフ as *beourufu* in Hepburn and as *beouruhu* in Nihon-shiki/Kunrei-shiki/Wāpuro.

Comment: My intuition tells that they should be ベオウルフ{LHHLL} and ベオールフ{LHLLL} (Tokyo accent).

Comment: @broccoliforest I thought the pitch drop in ベオールフ would be somewhere between オ and ル, but not at the very beginning of ー, so I wrote ベオールフ{LHHLL}. Feel free to correct me (edit my posts), though, I'm no native speaker.

Comment: In either case, the pitch on ウ is lower in ベオールフ than in ベオウルフ.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Phonetically you might be right that オー forms a continual pitch slope, but we perceive it as an ordinary 2nd mora high word like ドミニオン{LHLLL}, for Tokyo accent system doesn't really have rise/fall morae.

Comment: At least, it'll make some inconsistency if you write it that way in this notation.

Comment: @broccoliforest Thank you! By the way, do you have any recommendations for reading about pitch accent (either English or Japanese)?

Comment: @Earthliŋ As far as I know most of the recent works on loanword accents are published in each paper rather than books. How about http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.370.6811&rep=rep1&type=pdf, http://www.f.waseda.jp/uenok/ronshu/ronshu_01_sakamoto.pdf or http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/pmod/practical/02-06-01.php. [新明解アクセント辞典](http://dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/dicts/ja/newm_accja2/) seems to have an overview about accent rule.

Comment: That said, every source I gave above contains examples against my introspection... The accentuation of loanwords could be very fluid, and changes with times.